# Change css of relative element based on change or click in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a form with custom styled input component in react material ui,it goes something like this

```
onst StyledInputElement = styled('input')(`
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: IBM Plex Sans, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.4375em;
  background: rgb(243, 246, 249);
  border: 1px solid #E5E8EC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  color: #20262D;
  transition: width 300ms ease;

  &:hover {
    background: #EAEEF3;
    border-color: #E5E8EC;
  }

  &:focus {
    outline: none;
    width: 320px;
    transition: width 200ms ease-out;
  }
`);

const CustomInput = React.forwardRef(function CustomInput(props, ref) {
  return (
    <InputUnstyled components={{ Input: StyledInputElement }} {...props} ref={ref} />
  );
});


const AuthDialog = (props) => {

  return (
    <>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Dialog
        fullWidthS
        onClose={() => {}}
        open={props.dilaogOpenProp}
        maxWidth="xs"
        sx={{
          backdropFilter: "blur(3px)",
        }}
      >
        <DialogTitle>Please login</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
        <CustomInput aria-label="Demo input" placeholder="Username" />
        <br/>
        <CustomInput onClick aria-label="Demo input" placeholder="Password" />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={props.handleDialogCloseProp}>Close</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
      <Box
        sx={{
          minHeight: "100vh",
          background:
            "url(https://source.unsplash.com/random) no-repeat center center",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
        }}
      ></Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

export default AuthDialog;

Now it works something like this

[image: Before click]

[image]

As you can see on clicking one of the text fields is expanding but that leaves another text field to its same size, how do I apply text field expands CSS on both of the text fields even if I click any one of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:focus-within` on the parent of the two inputs.

```js
const StyledContainer = styled('div')(`
   &:focus-within input {
     outline: none;
     width: 320px;
     transition: width 200ms ease-out;
   }
`)
```

Then surround your two inputs with this container:

```
<StyledContainer>
  <CustomInput aria-label="Demo input" placeholder="Username" />
  <br/>
  <CustomInput onClick aria-label="Demo input" placeholder="Password" />
</StyledContainer>
```

(**Note:** not supported by IE11)